# Automatic backups for MySQL Workbench

Tags: backup, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to schedule AUTOMATIC backups for specific tables in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: What is an "automatic" backup? Or do you just mean that you want to schedule backups?

Comment: MySQL workbench isn't a backup tool in itself.  You'll need to give us more info on what version of MySQL, what kind of server it's on (e.g. Windows, Linux), what access you have to the server before we can really help.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL Workbench is a client querying and modelling tool and a very good one at that - it's purpose is not to perform server tasks - that's the job of the server. You can perform manual backups using Workbench, but I'm assuming that's not your long term goal.

There are many ways you can perform backups. Take a look [here](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html) for 10 of them. Some of the solutions are OS dependent - basically, you have more choices if you're on Linux/*nix than on Windows (which are you?). Also, it depends on whether your tables are InnoDB or MyISAM (hope it's InnoDB!).

Two (other Open Source) backup solutions not mentioned in the post above are Percona's [XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) which can be cron'd or [Zmanda](http://amanda.zmanda.com/)'s (which was mentioned in the [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) book by Schwartz et al.). Another solution would be [MyDumper](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/03/10/new-mydumper-0-6-1-release-offers-several-performance-and-usability-features/) - again a Percona backed tool (except this one also copes with MyISAM tables).

If you're familiar with *nix and file systems, then maybe an LVM solution might be for you? Try [here](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/).

I would advise you to study the solutions available and do some testing and see which one best suits your requirements.